# "Big" scrollbar for spinner

Tags: android, scrollbar, spinner, scrollview

I have a spinner with huge amount of items, so the simple scrolling is very slow for user. I want to use "Big" touchable scrollbar or it like in ScrollView. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a spinner with huge amount of items

This is part of your problem. :) Think of Spinners as being similar to dropdown boxes in desktop or web UIs. No user wants to use one to search through "a huge amount of items." That's not what they're for.

Consider breaking out this particular selection process into its own Dialog or possibly even its own Activity. From there you can offer a much richer interface for making this choice, which might include a ListView with fast scrolling enabled, (if the adapter implements [`SectionIndexer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html) then fast scrolling will let the user jump between sections easily,) and maybe a permanent text field so that the user can live-filter content down to something more manageable.

Answer (score 1):

The listview element of your layout should be able to use the attribute of:

```
android:fastScrollEnabled
```